# return makes pointer integer without a cast - binary trees

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I'm writing a function for binary trees that will find a desired node using an unsigned int.

my problem is I get the warning "return makes pointer from integer without a cast", it's probably something really simple I missed out but i can't seem to find it, please help.

also the "return (*B)->prod.prodID" is the one with the warning, thank you.

```
struct BST** nodeFinder(struct BST **B,unsigned int iden)
{

   if((*B)->prod.prodID == iden){
         return (*B)->prod.prodID;
   }
   if(iden < (*B)->prod.prodID){
           nodeFinder(&(*B)->lchild,iden);
   }else{
         nodeFinder(&(*B)->rchild,iden);
   }
   (*B)->rchild = NULL;
   return &(*B)->rchild;
}
```

Comment: Return proper thing instead of `(*B)->prod.prodID`, which may have type `unsigned int`.

Comment: How is `BST` defined? What this function is expected to do?

Comment: Using `&` in a return statement is almost surely wrong.

Comment: @iharob I don't think so. It might be returning where to modify later.

Comment: Certainly `(*B)->prod.prodID;` and `&(*B)->rchild`  are not the same type, yet both are return values.

Comment: ITYM `return B;` on that line

Answer (score 0):

You have to return **address of (*B)** instated of **unsigned int ((*B)->prod.prodID)**
because of your return type is (**B) type.
 Something like :

```
if((*B)->prod.prodID == iden)
{
return (*B)->lchild;
//or
return (*B)->rchild;
}
```